# Download files using Laravel's Storage facade

Tags: php, laravel

I've got a directory `dl` in `storage/app/` directory, and I managed to get the files content using `Storage::get(dl/filename.ext)`
But now I wanna make a download link for those files, and I'm kinda confused by how does Response and Storage facade work.
I'm using Response facade with a defined route like this :

```
Route::get('site/download/{fileName}', function($fileName) {
    $path = storage_path().'/app/dl/'.$fileName;

    return Response::download($path, $fileName);
});
```

Note: I'm using Laragon, site is the root directory.
The problem occuring is `Unable to guess the mime type as no guessers are available (Did you enable the php_fileinfo extension?)` . I know this is a known problem but after searching for a solution, I didn't find something that would fit my needs. The files are C files, mime type should be 'text/plain' probably, but I don't know how and where to specify it.
I also looked for other solutions, but `file does not exists` kept showing up.
I need something to download files from `storage/app/dl/`.

Answer (score 0):

Your path contains the filename, hence the 'file does not exists'

This worked for me:

```
Route::get('test', function() {

   $pathToFile = storage_path('app/test.txt');

   return response()->download($pathToFile);

});
```

Comment: It actually shortened how I wrote it, so it's more clear... that's good...but it still tells me some mime type error, that can't be guessed, by some php_fileinfo mistery wizard....